# Frequent MySQL table corruptions and instability

Tags: mysql, aws

The database I'm working on is having frequent issues.

Almost every day there is a problem.

Things like tables crashing or becoming corrupt.

So far, they've been repairable in one way or another, however I'm curious what the cause is exactly.

Bad hardware is always a possibility, but because I'm using Amazon's Web Services, I'm doubtful that is the case.

I've been monitoring the CPU usage on the machine and I've noticed that it frequently maxes out. On average, it hovers around 40%, but has frequent spikes.

Would constant high usage be a cause for my issues? If so, what is a good way of handling the high usage apart from optimizing queries; I'm currently working on that and the high usage is likely to stay.  Would replication be beneficial?

**EDIT -- I went ahead and bit the bullet and decided to upgrade the resources. So far, I've been able to run all my queries without any issues. It looks like I was just working it too hard.**

Comment: What MySQL version are you using, and what storage engine(s) do you use?

Comment: I haven't tried using a new instance--I could probably try that although it's several GB in size so I'm reluctant to creating a new instance and copying it. Also, I'm using MySQL 5.5.20

Answer (score 2):

High CPU usually means inefficient queries.  Let's see the slow queries, together with SHOW CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN.

The solution may be as simple as adding an index.  Or perhaps reformulating the query.  A common inefficiency is using a subquery instead of a JOIN.

You can't tune your way out of CPU troubles.  Throwing hardware at it is, at best, a temporary solution.

Comment: I don't think inefficient queries are the main perpetrator here. I've added indexes on all columns used for lookups and don't use any subqueries--just joins. I suspect the main issue is just the sheer volume of queries performed (there are a lot and they run basically all day everyday). I think this may be a case where a hardware upgrade is necessary.

Comment: No, adding indexes does not necessarily cure such a problem.  In fact, it may aggravate it.  Turn on the slowlog; then let's discuss the worst query that it finds.

Comment: Well I've turned on slow logs and let it run for about a day and no queries have come up. Now I'm going to drop long_query_time down to 1 sec to see if I can get some queries to show up.

Comment: I'd lower the `long_query_time` to 0.0 seconds (yes zero) for a whole day or for 30-60 minutes (so you don't have a huge query log).